# How many rows of data can karate "read(file.csv)" can read?

Tags: json, csv, karate

I am trying to read and print the data from a csv file using below karate scenario outline code snippet. the CSV file contains more than 350 rows of data with 2 columns "Description" and "Expression". But when I execute the below code snippet its running for more than 1hr and not generating any cucumber reports.

Note: the same code snippet works fine when the CSV file contains 50-100 rows

```
Scenario Outline: <Description>
And def result = {"items":{"name":'#(Description)',"expression":'#(Expression)'}}
Then def rule_description =  result.items.name
Then print rule_description
Then def rule_expression =  result.items.expression
Then print rule_expression

Examples:
  | data_file |
```

Can someone please help and guide me what am I missing here.

Comment: old versions of karate had issues. my recommendation is you provide a way for us to replicate and we will fix it. follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - you can see an example of how someone did this in the past here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/661

Comment: Fwiw, I recently had a Karate scenario read a 200k row CSV, run the data through a decryption method, and write the results to a separate CSV file.  I turned logging/HTML reporting off and the whole thing took ~2 minutes.